# Cannot view files written in sd card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I use the code below in order to save a file in my sdcard. The code is taken by another post in stackoverflow. The file is written in the card successfully and i can view it in my phone. However i noticed that i cannot view the file when i connect my phone in the computer. I also noticed that the contents of the folder ext_card are showing in my computer and not the contents of the folder sdcard.

Here is the code

```
      File dir = new File ("/mnt/ext_card" + "/mine");
       dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir, "capture.csv");
        try {
        f = new FileOutputStream(file);
        captureFile = new PrintWriter(f);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
```

I write it inside the ext folder and i cannot view it again.

Comment: With MTP based devices you have to notify the MTP engine that you have created a new file before it will be made visible to an MTP client computer.

Comment: Please look in your folder using adb shell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654432/android-sd-card-created-file-not-visible

The link above has an answer that works.